# How to avoid a Note about `assign` when checking a package (where `do.call` cannot be used)

Tags: r

I am using `assign` to get around [scoping issues in the `car` package, as suggested by the package's authors](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/car/vignettes/embedding.pdf). This gives me a `Note` when a check the pages using `devtools::check`.

The standard workaround for this seems to be to use `do.call`. However, near as I can tell, that only works when using functions that don't extract data from the environment (i.e., which let you pass in the data as arguments), which is not my situation.

### Example of where I use assign

Note that `residualPlots` extracts `.estimation.data` and `.formula` from the environment.

```
assign(".estimation.data", model$estimation.data, envir=.GlobalEnv)
assign(".formula", model$formula, envir=.GlobalEnv)
t <- residualPlots(model$original)
remove(".formula", envir=.GlobalEnv)
remove(".estimation.data", envir=.GlobalEnv)
```

### Instructions for replication

I've included these instructions for replication due to it being good practice. But, I doubt that much is to be learned by replicating.
 1. Clone: https://github.com/Displayr/flipRegression
 2. Build the package (I am using RStudio)
 3. `devtools::check(cleanup = FALSE, args = c('--no-build-vignettes','--no-manual','--no-tests'))`

### The note

```
checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
Found the following assignments to the global environment:
File 'flipRegression/R/regressiondiagnostics.R':
   assign(".estimation.data", model$estimation.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".formula", model$formula, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".estimation.data", .estimation.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".formula", model$formula, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".design", model$design, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".estimation.data", x$estimation.data, envir = .GlobalEnv)
   assign(".formula", formula(model), envir = .GlobalEnv)
 R CMD check results
 0 errors | 0 warnings | 1 note 
 Warning message:
 `cleanup` is deprecated 
 R CMD check succeeded
```

Comment: It seems your package depends on a few packages available only on github, it is not easy to replicate your situation.  That said, the note clearly tells you that you are copying an object on global environment, which presumably unnecessary for your purpose.  Skimming your codes, it looks like you make a copy of variables on the global with `assign` function, then remove them without using them.  So I wonder why you need to create these variables in the first place.

Comment: The `residualPlots` function takes the variables from the environment (i.e., they are not passed in directly). What I am doing is precisely what the car package authors advise is the appropriate way to use their function (see the link at the beginning of my question).

Comment: In the pages 3-4 of the car document, the author calls `m1 <- lm(.meanmod, .dta)` after `assign` them.  But in your `residualPlots.Regression` code, I don't see the assigned variables are used before they are removed.  So I wonder if you really need them.

Comment: `lm` and `residualPlots` work differently. `lm` does not take the data from the environment in the example you have provided. `residualPlots` does. By all means run the example and remove the assign and you will see that the result changes.

Comment: Hmm, anyways, the note says that copying an object to global environment requires a care.  It is not prohibited since it is only a note.  In order to avoid that, you will need to change `.GlobalEnv` to somewhere else.  I am not sure which environment is appropriate to achieve your goal though.

Comment: Are you saying that this change will solve the problem, or, are you just speculating? (I ask, because I think that what you are proposing will just cause a different bug, as the whole point of assign is to put it in the global environment.)

Comment: Okay, let me be clear.  My suggestion is to check if you really need to use `assign` to achieve your goal.  The examples in `car` documentation probably is valid approach to use on the global environment, but may not be appropriate to do within package implementation (at least it raises notes).  If you would like to use `assign` approach, then I would suggest to ignore the notes, since they are just notes, not warning or error.  If you would like to avoid the notes while using `assign` approach, then I would suggest to change the direction somewhere other than the global.

Comment: As you say, this may create other bugs.  However, a package in general should not make changes on the global environment.  Users will be surprised if variables have been changed only by importing it.  I think you really should a way to achieve your goal without copying stuff on the global, or just ignore the notes.